# Firewall rule to allow VM connection to the internet

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall, vpn

I have a Windows VM on GCE that is connected to an on prem network via VPN. I set up GCP firewall rules that will allow access to this VM only by ip address on the on-prem network. My problem is that I need to find a way to let this VM reach the internet.

I'm trying to reach a proxy server on the internet with this VM. I set up the following configurations on the firewall settings of the VM:
On-prem network: 10.x.x.x.

Ingress rules:
Ports and Protocol- ALL
Source IP range: 10.x.x.x

Egress rules:
Ports and Protocol- ALL
Destination IP range: 10.x.x.x

I still cannot reach the internet through this set up.

Should my Egress rule's Destination IP be changed to 0.0.0/0 to allow any networks?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [static route](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#addingroute) in GCP with destination IP address (Proxy server) and next hop VPN tunnel and to make sure that only that VM use that static route, you can specify a instance [tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) and add it to the VM